# Twitter stream API - Erlang client

Tags: twitter, stream, erlang, client

I'm very new in Erlang world and I'm trying to write a client for the Twitter Stream API. I'm using httpc:request to make a POST request and I constantly get 401 error, I'm obviously doing something wrong with how I'm sending the request... What I have looks like this:

```
fetch_data() ->
    Method = post,
    URL = "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json",
    Headers = "Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"XXX\", oauth_nonce=\"XXX\", oauth_signature=\"XXX%3D\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"XXX\", oauth_token=\"XXX-XXXXX\", oauth_version=\"1.0\"",
    ContentType = "application/json",
    Body = "{\"track\":\"keyword\"}",
    HTTPOptions = [],
    Options = [],
    R = httpc:request(Method, {URL, Headers, ContentType, Body}, HTTPOptions, Options),
    R.
```

At this point I'm confident there's no issue with the signature as the same signature works just fine when trying to access the API with curl. I'm guessing there's some issue with how I'm making the request.

The response I'm getting with the request made the way demonstrated above is:

```
{ok,{{"HTTP/1.1",401,"Unauthorized"},
 [{"cache-control","must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store"},
  {"connection","close"},
  {"www-authenticate","Basic realm=\"Firehose\""},
  {"content-length","1243"},
  {"content-type","text/html"}],
 "<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"/>\n<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<h2>HTTP ERROR: 401</h2>\n<p>Problem accessing '/1.1/statuses/filter.json'. Reason:\n<pre>    Unauthorized</pre>\n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n</body>\n</html>\n"}}
```

When trying with curl I'm using this:

```
curl --request 'POST' 'https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json' --data 'track=keyword' --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="XXX", oauth_nonce="XXX", oauth_signature="XXX%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="XXX", oauth_token="XXX-XXXX", oauth_version="1.0"' --verbose
```

and I'm getting the events just fine.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, new with Erlang and I've been pulling my hair out on this one for quite a while.

Comment: I use oauth:get/6 (https://github.com/tim/erlang-oauth) to connect to their stream at `statuses/sample`, you can use `oauth:post` for the filtering stream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There are several issues with your code**:

1. In Erlang you are encoding parameters as a JSON body while with `curl`, you are encoding them as form data (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). Twitter API expects the latter. In fact, you get a 401 because the OAuth signature does not match, as you included the `track=keyword` parameter in the computation while Twitter's server computes it without the JSON body, as it should per [OAuth RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849).
2. You are using [`httpc`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html) with default options. This will not work with the streaming API as the stream never ends. You need to process results as they arrive. For this, you need to pass  `{sync, false}` option to [`httpc`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html). See also `stream` and `receiver` options.

Eventually, while `httpc` can work initially to access Twitter streaming API, it brings little value to the code you need to develop around it to stream from Twitter API. Depending on your needs you might want to replace it a simple client directly built on [`ssl`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html), especially considering it can decode HTTP packets (what is left for you is the HTTP chunk encoding).

For example, if your keywords are rare, you might get a timeout from `httpc`. Besides, it might be easier to update the list of keywords or your code with no downtime without `httpc`.

**A streaming client directly based on [`ssl`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html)** could be implemented as a `gen_server` (or a simple process, if you do not follow OTP principles) or even better a `gen_fsm` to implement reconnection strategies. You could proceed as follows:

- Connect using [`ssl:connect/3,4`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html#connect-3) specifying that you want the socket to decode the HTTP packets with [`{packet, http_bin}`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#setopts-2) and you want the socket to be configured in passive mode [`{active, false}`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#setopts-2).
- Send the HTTP request packet (preferably as an iolist, with binaries) with [`ssl:send/2,3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html#send-2). It shall spread on several lines separated with CRLF (`\r\n`), with first the query line (`GET /1.1/statuses/filter.json?... HTTP/1.1`) and then the headers including the OAuth headers. Make sure you include `Host: stream.twitter.com` as well. End with an empty line.
- Receive the HTTP response. You can implement this with a loop (since the socket is in passive mode), calling [`ssl:recv/2,3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html#recv-2) until you get `http_eoh` (end of headers). Note down whether the server will send you data chunked or not by looking at the `Transfer-Encoding` response header.
- Configure the socket in active mode with [`ssl:setopts/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html#setopts-2) and specify you want packets as raw and data in binary format. In fact, if data is chunked, you could continue to use the socket in passive mode. You could also get data line by line or get data as strings. This is a matter of taste: raw is the safest bet, line by line requires that you check the buffer size to prevent truncation of a long JSON-encoded tweet.
- Receive data from Twitter as messages sent to your process, either with `receive` (simple process) or in `handle_info` handler (if you implemented this with a `gen_server`). If data is chunked, you shall first receive the chunk size, then the tweets and the end of the chunk eventually (cf [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1)). Be prepared to have tweets that spread on several chunks (i.e. maintain some kind of buffer). The best here is to do the minimum decoding in this process and send tweets to another process, possibly in binary format.

You should also handle errors and socket being closed by Twitter. Make sure you follow [Twitter's guidelines for reconnection](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/connecting#Reconnecting).

Comment: I have been successfully using `erlang-oauth` library to connect to twitter's stream, and `erlang-oauth` seems to use `httpc`: https://github.com/tim/erlang-oauth/blob/118e9f7284c81cb72e131e20bcecf5872a5cbe97/src/oauth.erl#L192. Would you please explain why are you saying that `httpc` won't work?

Comment: You are correct, httpc will work in asynchronous mode. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @PaulGuyot Thanks for the help. I have now successfully opened a socket to stream.twitter.com and seems that this part is working just fine. I am, however, having issues with sending the request over the socket in the right way. I have tried with `ssl:send(SSLSocket, "POST /1.1/statuses/filter.json?oauth_consumer_key=XXX...`, with `ssl:send(SSLSocket, "POST %2F1.1%2Fstatuses%2Ffilter.json%26oauth_consumer_key%3DXXX` and other formats but it seems I cannot get it right. How is one expected to send headers over a socket? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @akonsu Thanks for jumping in on this. Do you have a short example on how you have accomplished this with erlang-oauth? I cannot seems to find a good example for this, I can only see examples on how to get through with the OAuth part but not for how to make requests. Thanks

Comment: @PaulGuyot would you please point me to a sample code that uses `ssl` in a streaming client? I am also building a twitter stream consumer, and to me it also seems that `httpc` adds little value.

Comment: @Thanos I used this convoluted code as an example: https://github.com/naoyat/erlang-oauth-stream

Comment: @Thanos You should encode a complete HTTP request, and also I believe Twitter expects a GET for /1.1/statuses/filter.json. Make sure you pass OAuth in headers. @akonsu I am not aware of an open source Twitter streaming client based on `ssl`, but I updated the answer to detail, step by step, how you could proceed. It is a matter of less than 500 LOC.